# How to make visible and invisible an image by clicking a button in android studio?

Tags: android

i have two activities in android studio.act1 with a button and act2 with an imageView. i want to click the button in act1 and make the image in act2 visible. and when i click button for second time, this time make the image invisible and do it again and again and again. how can i do that?

Comment: toggle a boolean in Act1, pass that to Act2 to use

Comment: i dont know how do it. please write the codes.tnx

Comment: Please follow the practices for asking questions if you want a good answer
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must create this class;

```html
public class PublicSharedPreferences {
    public static void setDefaults(String key, String value, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getDefaults(String key, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(key, null);
    }
}
```

and then learn sharedpreferences [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Activity1;

```html
public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout1);

        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String visibilityStr = PublicSharedPreferences.getDefaults("keyVisibility", getApplicationContext());

               if (visibilityStr != null) {
                if (visibilityStr.equals("0")) {
                    Toast.makeText(Activity1.this, "it visibled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    visibilityStr = "1";
                } else {
                    visibilityStr = "0";
                    Toast.makeText(Activity1.this, "it invisibled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                visibilityStr = "1";
                Toast.makeText(Activity1.this, "it visibled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

                PublicSharedPreferences.setDefaults("keyVisibility", visibilityStr, getApplicationContext());

                Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
                Activity1.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Activity2;

```html
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout2);

        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView1);

        String visibilityStr = PublicSharedPreferences.getDefaults("keyVisibility", getApplicationContext());

        if (visibilityStr.equals("0"))
            imgView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        else
            imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Layout1;

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.c.a.myapplication.Activity1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout2;

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Its work.

Comment: thats what i want. it works well,tnx. but just one another question: how can i add a toast when image set visible: "it visibled" and when it set invisible add a toast:"it invisibled" ? tnx again.

Comment: you will write your toast message below imgView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) in if block

Comment: it dosent work well. the toast shows when i go to Activity2. but i dont want it. i want to display toast in Activity1 when i click the button. can you help me?

Comment: It works well. Thanks. And one another quetion :) . Thats the last question, i think :)))) . I set a picture as button background in Activity1. I want the button in Act1 change its background when i click it ( when picture visibled in Act2) and when i clicked it for second time( when picture invisibled in Act2) restore the background to the first condition. Do you know how can i do that?

Comment: You write btn.setBackgroundResource("...") below the each toast message code.

Comment: hi. its works well. tnx. but it dosent save. when i exit the activity and go back to it again, the background is gone and it dosent save :(

Comment: can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code....

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Sample extends Activity {
    ImageView img;
    Button btn;
    boolean clicked = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.t1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                clicked = true;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Sample.this, Dample.class);
                intent.putExtra("value", true);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

    }
}
```

//Dample.class In second activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Dample extends Activity {
     ImageView img;//use image view

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pimple);
        img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
        Boolean yourBool = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("value");
        if (yourBool == true) {
            img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);///use visibility code for     imageview as mentioned above
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: excuse me, but it dosent work. can you write whole codes completely without any deficit plz? im new in coding :(

Comment: and please dont use Intent. i dont want go to the act2 when image bacame visible or invisible. i want to go there another time. just make image visible and invisible. tnx